# Can nonvisual WinForms controls be used from WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

Can nonvisual WinForms controls be used from WPF, as long as they are instantiated programmatically? I am comparing two sets of components that are only available for WinForms, yet we want to create WPF apps "going forward."

Comment: Why would you have a non-visual control? It seems like that could only be useful for message passing.  If so then I would build the abstraction on top of `SynchronizationContext` which works in both WPF and WinForms

Comment: What is a non-visual Control? You instantiate it but do not show it?
Although it seems awkward, i see no problem of creating an instance and access to its properties in a WPF context.
Have you tried anything and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: Okay, nonvisual component - such as OracleConnection, OracleCommand, etc.

Comment: What I'm saying is, since these components are not available for WPF (not for installation in the Toolbox), is there a way that I can nevertheless use them in a WPF app, e.g. by instantiating the components in code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you reference the the correct dll any object from any assembly and namespace can be used. The big question is whether that is the right thing to do.

It would help tremendously if you mentioned which two sets of components you are referencing as we may know of a WPF only solution, hence saving you from having to reference WinForms.

Comment: The two sets of components are Oracles native set (ODP) and devArt's dotConnect components.